# Finding the maximum difference between two same sized rows while ignoring blank cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, difference, array-difference

I have two rows, `A` (assumed to not have any nulls) and `B` (can contain blank cells) in Excel. `A` and `B` are both the same length.

What is the correct Excel formula to compute the maximum positive increase between `A` and `B`?

Example:

```
Row A = [10, 4, 8, 20, 4, 5, 7, 2, 9, 5]
Row B = [0, 20, 4, null, 10, 9, 2, null, null, null]

Expected answer for A - B: max([10 - 0, 4 - 20, 8 - 4, 4 - 10, 5 - 9, 7 - 2]) = max(10, -16, 4, -6, -4, 5) = 10
```

If `Row B` is all `null`, the expected answer for `A - B` is `null`.

I would like to avoid creating a new row to compute this value.

Comment: Is the maximum difference not 16 then?

Comment: @JMP Yes sorry for the poor terminology. I'm looking specifically for the largest positive increase between two rows.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have row A data from A1 to J1 and row B data from A2 to J2.

Then you can use this array function to skip the difference if cell is blank in the row B then calculate the maximum of differences using the array function as:

```
=MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:J2)),A1:J1-A2:J2))
```

To enter the array function, after you type or paste above function, press Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

[image: example]

References:
https://www.excel-easy.com/functions/array-formulas.html and
https://exceljet.net/formula/max-if-criteria-match

Answer (score 3):

Or try this non-array formula,

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,(A2:J2<>"")*(A1:J1-A2:J2),1)
```

Comment: If you wanted to allow for a situation where all changes were negative, then =AGGREGATE(14,6,(A4:J4-A5:J5)/(A5:J5<>""),1) could be preferable (the way the question is phrased, this probably shouldn't happen).

Comment: Aggregate is an array formula with the only difference being that it is a native array formula. The same restrictions on range reference should be adhered. The only difference is that native array formula do not require ctrl-shift-enter in older versions.